# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

Added a form to the DetailView, I'm trying to create an entry through the form, I get an error

```
*AttributeError at /card/3/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/card/3/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Super\Desktop\projects\пед проэкт\cards\views.py, line 19, in get_success_url
Raised during:  cards.views.CardDetailView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Super\Desktop\projects\пед проэкт\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Super\\Desktop\\projects\\пед проэкт',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\Desktop\\projects\\пед проэкт\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Super\\Desktop\\projects\\пед проэкт\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 14 Apr 2023 10:00:23 +0000*
```

**My views**
I don’t even know why this problem got out, it seems that I did everything according to the dock

```
class CardDetailView(SuccessMessageMixin, ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Card
    template_name = 'cards/detail.html'
    success_message = 'Ваше сообщение об ошибке получено. Мы обязательно займемся этим.'
    form_class = WrongCardsForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CardDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.author = self.request.user
            form.card = self.get_object()
            form.save()
            super(CardDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(CardDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**My forms**

```
class WrongCardsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WrongCards
        fields = ['mistake_in', 'error_text',]
        # fields = '__all__'
```

**My urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CardsListView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.CardDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**My models**

```
class WrongCards(models.Model):
    """Карточки с ошибками"""
    CHOICE = ((None, 'Выберите в чем ошибка'), ('a', 'терминe'), ('b', 'определение'), ('c', 'произношение'))
    mistake_in = models.CharField('Ошибка в', choices=CHOICE, max_length=3)
    card = models.ForeignKey('Card', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Ошибка', related_name='wrong_cards')
    error_text = models.TextField('Подробнее об ошибки')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mistake_in


class Card(models.Model):
    """Карточки слов"""
    term = models.CharField('Термин', max_length=100)
    transcription = models.CharField('Транскрипция', max_length=100)
    definition = models.CharField('Определение', max_length=100)
    audi = models.FileField(upload_to='audi/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='Произношение',
                            validators=[validators.RegexValidator(regex=".mp3")], )
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', verbose_name='Фото')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    created = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Дата последнего редактирования', auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.term} - {self.definition}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Карточку"
        verbose_name_plural = "Карточки"
        ordering = ['-created']
```

What I tried didn't work for me. I'm just starting to learn Django.

Comment: Please add full error traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did, described in text

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrong about the import class, I changed the ModelFormMixin class to FormMixin